# SAP Business Objects Query Builder Query - SI_SESSION_USER

Tags: query-builder, business-objects

I am trying to get a list of all connections where the SI_SESSION_USER='xyz'.

When I do a query like 
select * from si_infoobjects where si_id='00000', I can see this field in the results with that value (xyz).

When I modify the query to look for that specific field and value, it returns zero rows.

I am using:
select * from si_infoobjects where SI_SESSION_USER='xyz'

What query will return the correct results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess here, but si_session_user is probably in the Processing Info bag.  So use this:

```
select * 
 from ci_infoobjects 
where si_processinfo.SI_SESSION_USER='xyz'
```

Note that that's **ci_infoobjects** not **si_infoobjects**, but I assume that's just a typo in your question.

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know of any documentation that notes how t access all the fields one on one? For a lot of them you can see them with a select *, but the you query for that specific field it returns nothing, like this one did.

Comment: There's some documentation in the BI4 Platform SDK Developers Guide, but it's very scant: http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir4/en/xi4_boejava_dg_en.zip